# Site management and application context TYPO3 9

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

In TYPO3 9 is a new feature `Site Management`, where a 'Site Configuration' can be created. Among the requested fields there is 'Entry point' where the domain name can be given which will be used for creating 'full URLs', allowing to renounce an extension like RealUrl.

After filling in the fields a file gets created at `/config/sites/mysite/config.yaml`

How can this file be loaded or change settings in it, depending on the so called application context / environment variable TYPO3_CONTEXT, since different domain names will be used for development, testing and production. Also locales could be spelled different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at 9.5 LTS; the ticket https://forge.typo3.org/issues/86303 has been resolved with the "site variants"; I add here a screenshot of the Site Configuration module with a variant added (taken from the latest TYPO3 Master).

[image: screenshot of site configuration with added variant]

Comment: But how to deal with locales? On my development machine the locale is spelled different then on the server. For example nl_NL.UTF-8 (Mac) and nl_NL.utf-8 (Linux)

Comment: Riccardo Would be great if you could add an example or deeper explanation. Link-only answers are likely being removed ;-)

Answer (score 0):

At the moment it isn't possible. We deploy different files to the different systems for this ... Ticket is https://forge.typo3.org/issues/86303